# What is written in the EFI partition ? In details

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, uefi

- I have a HDD(called HDD1) with some partitions such as EFI partition and windows 10 partition.
- I have another HDD (called HDD2) with only a EFI partition and windows 10 partition.

I would like to replace the windows partition from HDD2 to HDD1. (kind of restoration)

**What should I replace from the EFI partition of HDD2 to HDD1 in order to be able to boot on windows ?**

- Could you tell me in details what there are inside the EFI partition ? (the bit/sector start of the windows/linux/any_other_OS partition ?)
- Is there any unique ID for each windows inside the EFI ? (means just replacing the windows partitions/files is not enough)

I'd like to know the EFI system in a low level in order to know what is possible to do or not.

*Assumption: The windows partition of HDD2 is same size or smaller than the HDD1's one.*

**Edited:** By just replacing the windows partition, it's working. Means in the EFI partition, there is no information about windows installed. But I don't get why there are so many files in the EFI partition.

Comment: Yes! there are information about windows installed! In `%Systmroot%\system32` you'll find 2 files called `winload.exe` and `winload.efi`. In MBR/BIOS based installations, Boot Configuration Data (BCD) on System Partition, points to `winload.exe` and in GPT/EFI based installations points to `winload.efi`. That's why it worked without changing boot files (anyway, you still have same file in same location). The interesting part is, if you replace HDD1 windows partition with HDD2's, and HDD1 was an MBR disk, you would still get to boot it! because `winload.exe` is there too.

Comment: But both are EFI windows and it worked... `%Systemroot%` is not on the EFI partition but on the windows partition, then of course it contains details about installed windows.

Comment: Read the comment once again

Comment: Sorry, `there are information about windows installed!`, when I said information, it's more `unique information` which could be a problem if I replace only the windows partition. Then no, if the new replaced partition has a `winload.efi` file, it's ok. Good! Thank you and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem. Actually, Yes! There are "unique information" in some cases. If you enable Secure Boot on an EFI system which supports it, you can only boot to the one that boot files are created for. It checks booting windows file's fingerprint to make sure there's no malicious code trying to run.

Comment: Oh ok, I don't use it for now then it's ok. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the efi partition, there is the efi boot loader in the directory /EFI/boot, and on a x64 system the file bootx64.efi is loaded, on a x86 system the file bootia32.efi is started. No sector addresses or similar are needed, because the EFI understands the file system (FAT32).

Windows stores its boot configuration in the directory /Microsoft/Boot/, namely in the file BCD (which is a registry hive with the boot settings) and various language files in respective sub-directories.

The BCD file stores entries for the boot loader, and addresses the partitions (at least on GPT systems) via their unique ID. So simply copying a given BCD to another disk won’t work, as the unique IDs won’t match, and Windows will stop booting with the error 0xC0000255.

You can use a tool like bcdedit to fix that, or Visual BCD editor.

Comment: `x64 system` / `x86 system` is not really correct/precise. Which "fallback" EFI executable to load depends on whether the UEFI is 32-bit or 64-bit, but has nothing to do with the CPU (which `x86`/`x(86_)64` are specifically referring to). Also, most of the UEFI will fall back to `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` first, even though it is Windows-specific and probably not mentioned at all in the UEFI spec.